# NSXMLParserErrorDomain in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I have set up a local server using XAMPP. I am making a request to the PHP pages , but i am getting an error as below:

"Parser Error : Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "Operation could not be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

What is this error due to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError
The document ended unexpectedly.
Try to trace loaded data to console before parsing